# Парсинг текста с тегами

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Привет всем!
Нужен ваш совет. Поиском пользовался. Гуглом тоже. Но видимо не научился находить нужную инфу.. 
Мне необходимо сделать нечто вроде парсера текста (с html-тегами) с сайта.
Необходимо удалять все запрещенные теги и все что между ними

```
 <div>
     содержание блока
    </div>
```

Но если блок между тегами codes не удалять его.

```
   <codes lang="css">
     //код
     </codes>
```

Если найден тег "codes" то заключить данный блог тегами "pre"

Comment: а вы не пробовали программу написать ? Это увлекательно и полезно! Для парсинга html существует великое множество библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки к размышлению

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ , http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Обход и обработка на примере XML

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($sxe->children() as $child) // обходим документ
{
$attrs = $child->attributes(); // получаем атрибуты
$name = $child->getName(); // получаем имя
...
if (твое условие)
{
// Модифицируешь документ
// $child->attributes(), addAtribute, addChild 
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Используй str_replace почитай о данной функции.